# Serialize to XML non-nested repeating sequence

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I need to serialize to an array which has multiple non-nested values i.e.

```
 <MyArray>
    <Code>code1</Code>
    <Name>name associated with code 1</Name>
    <Code>code2</Code>
    <Name>name associated with code 2</Name>
    <Code>code3</Code>
    <Name>name associated with code 3</Name>
    <Code>code4</Code>
    <Name>name associated with code 4</Name>
  </MyArray>
```

I've tried various attributes on my array - e.g.

```
[XmlArray(ElementName="MyArray")]        
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName="")]        
public List<MyPair> MyPairs { get; set; }
```

NB: the MyPair object contains 2 string properties (Code & Name):

but to no avail, I always get a containing element for each pair (which would normally be better but not what the schema demands - and over which I've no control). Any help greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** This is part of a huge xml document, is it possible to use manual serialization of XElement for 1 part of it and XMLSerialization for the rest?

Comment: I don't know if any way to get XmlSerializer to do that particular layout - AFAIK *you can't*. Maybe use something like XElement instead?

Comment: I agree with Marc, can not be done with the XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this off.  I worked around the problem with I think what could be called a bit of a hack as I wanted avoid serializing the entire object graph manually.  So:

- Used xml serialization to serialize to a string
- Manipulated the string to remove offending extra nested elements
- Parsed xml entire string to single XElement (required to allow this to be serialized correctly as xml for WCF)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a way other than serializing your items manually.

```
XElement xElem = new XElement("MyArray", 
                               array.Select(m => new XElement[] { 
                                               new XElement("Code", m.Code), 
                                               new XElement("Name", m.Name) })
                              );
var xml = xElem.ToString();
```

Comment: Marked up but not marked answer as this works if I were manually serializing the entire document but doesn't address the edit, if I add an XElement as a property to serialize it serializes in the manner I want but nests the entire XElement.